# Are Major Flat 6ths ever in music?

Tags: chords

I know that I have heard Ebb6 on the start of star wars theme song and I heard Bbb6 on another music at the end.

C Major 6th contains C, E, G, A.

Normally mb6 chords are used

I have heard them in some music

Are Major Flat 6ths really in music?

Comment: Apparently "yes" since you found them!  I'm not sure how true your "normally..." statement is -- there are rather a large number of musical styles, epochs, etc., and there's really no overarching set of rules.

Comment: By "major flat 6th" do you mean something like `C E G A♭`?

Comment: Yes, I mean something thike C, E, G, Ab.

Comment: They must be. Just like any other combination of four notes. Some composers have used them, others avoid. There is a dissonance which is useful in some styles, but dissonant chords have only  limited use.

Comment: Please review any of Duke Ellington's piano scores in Ab, Db, Eb. ...or perhaps, I don't understand the question

Answer (score 6):

I can't give a specific example, but the "major flat 6th" chord is a subset of the dominant ♭13 chord. If we're in the key of F major, for instance, the V♭13 would include `C E G` as the V chord and `A♭` as the ♭13.

Typically, ♭13 chords will also include a seventh (`B♭` in this case) and potentially even 9ths and 11ths (`D` and `F`). But these chords will certainly give you a place to start.

Comment: True. Once you've gone to a 7th, that '6th, or even b6th' note will be known as 13 or b13. But it seems OP has a slight obsession with purely a 4 note chord with a b6 included !

Answer (score 3):

**Often, in film scores**, *Major triads are played with their minor 6th used as a passing tone* (The Axiom's music in WALL-E, or pretty much any space/sci-fi soundtrack). So, in a way, one could analyse that as a Major ♭6 chord. Let me reiterate that it's **really common in film scores.**

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking in jazz 'scale=chord' terms there are scales that include the major 3rd and the b6, so I expect someone will have used a chord name like 'Cmaj11(b6)' (I think that includes one of everything?)

In more functional harmony, a b6 usually turns out to be a #5, replacing the 5th rather than additional to it.   But we allow 'C6' to break the 'pile of 3rds' system, so if you feel a crunchy b6 sounds good there's no reason not to allow 'C(b6)'.

In your question,  I think you may be confusing 'Cm6' where the third is minor with 'C(b6)' where the 6th is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you consider unresolved suspensions as a chord of their own?

In a minor scale, you can have a progression `#iv dim7 -- V -- i`, where you can have a suspension of the 7th between `iv#dim7` and `V`. If you never resolve this suspension, you'll basically have `V b6` chord (you might even have the 5th of this chord together with the `b6`).

E.g. in f minor, this would be `B D F Ab -- C G E Ab -- F C F Ab`

This way itself it would be very harsh (has a parallel 5th as well), but definitely in the right context pretty usable.

Answer (score -2):

The Chord Types:

1 - 3 - 5 - 0 —  6  (Major)
1 - 3 - 5 - 6b - 0  (Mystery)*
1 - 3 - 0 - 5# - 6  (Plus)

*Harmonic major.

The 0 is a space or vacancy position used only for comparing the chords.

Thus, it is seen that there is no augmented 5th or minor 6th in the major chord, no major 6th in the mystery chord, and no perfect 5th in the plus chord.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make sense of this answer. Are these scale degrees? What does "0" mean? Please explain more.